# Counting the number of rows of a series of csv files

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I'm working through an R tutorial and suspect that I have to use one of these functions but I'm not sure which (Yes I researched them but until I become more fluent in R terminology they are quite confusing).

In my working directory there is a folder "specdata". Specdata contains hundreds of CSV files named 001.csv - 300.csv.

The function I am working on must count the total number of rows for an inputed number of csv files. So if the argument in the function is `1:10` and each of those files has ten rows, return 100.

Here's what I have so far:

```
complete <- function(directory,id = 1:332) {
    setpath <- paste("/Users/gcameron/Desktop",directory,sep="/")
    setwd(setpath)
    csvfile <- sprintf("%03d.csv", id)
    file <- read.csv(csvfile)
    nrow(file)
 }
```

This works when the ID argument is one number, say 17. But, if I input say 10:50 as an argument, I receive an error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

What should I do to be able to count the total number of rows from the inputed ID parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`read.csv` expects to read just one file, so you need to loop over files, a R idiomatic way of doing so is to use `sapply`:

```
nrows <- sapply( csvfile, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)) )
sum(nrows)
```

For example, here is a rewrite of your `complete` function:

```
complete <- function(directory,id = 1:332) {
    csvfiles <- sprintf("/Users/gcameron/Desktop/%s/%03d.csv", directory, id)
    nrows <- sapply( csvfiles, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)) )
    sum(nrows)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So few follow up Q's if you have a sec.
1) Where do I put this line? Within the function "complete" or after it?
2) If after it, do I not have to declare the object csvfile again for scope?
3) Your parameter "function(f)" - is that just the name of the function I made in it's place? i.e. nrows <- sapply( csvfile, complete(f# what goes here?) nrow(read.csv(f)
As you can no doubt tell I'm struggling a bit with this

Comment: I've edited my answer. also note that your original function never reset the working directory when it is done, that's wrong.

Comment: Thanks a ton I'm really grateful for this. That has worked. Having now seen it I can make sense of it.

Comment: `length(count.fields(f))` is probably a lot quicker than `nrow(read.csv(f))`.  (You can test this hypothesis with `system.time`.)

Comment: I get a "Error in cc$id : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" error from trying this method.

Answer (score 1):

Homework problems usually get tagged as such, though I don't know if that is required, but this clearly is homework.

Your function as written expects that id is *not* a vector (despite the default value being a vector of integers).

Change it to either use one of the *apply functions (more concise and common), or even an explicit loop. For each element in the id vector, you must call a function that opens that file and counts the observations.

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) has a good explanation of the differences between the *apply functions.

Comment: [The homework tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: ok, thanks. I looked to see if that was covered in the faq, but didn't see it. I still think it's useful to know when it is homework, as I'm willing to provide a complete answer for someone trying to finish something at work, but would rather give hints and direction for homework.

Comment: This is indeed a good point, and I thought too that they would have added that to the faq since most users don't read the blog or metaSE.

Answer (score 0):

```
id <-c(1:332)
filenames=list.files(path="source_path", full.names=TRUE)

for(a in id){

    dataset <- read.csv(filenames[a])

    res <- nrow(na.exclude(dataset))  #nrow count the row of the dataset
    
    df <-data.frame(
    id =a,
    nobs =res,  
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}   

df
```

Answer (score 0):

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332){
  mylist <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = ".csv")
  result <- data.frame()
  for(i in id){
    my_data <- read.csv(paste(directory,mylist[i],sep=""))
    res <- nrow(na.exclude(my_data))  #nrow count the row of the dataset
    df <- data.frame("id" = i,"nobs" = res,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    result <- rbind(result,df)
  }
  return(result)
}
```